Are linear RBFs universal function approximators?
This paper shows that radial basis functions neural networks (RBFs NN, i.e., NN with one hidden layer with RBF activation) are universal function approximator (UVA). How about linear RBFs approximators, i.e., y = w*RBF(x) where RBF(x) is the same Gaussian activation and w is a weight vector? My understanding is that RBFs NN are slightly different, because every input is weighted before going through RBF(x), while in linear FA only the features post-activation is weighted. Are they also UVA? A few slides I found online say so, but without any reference.
